# Can I write a Non Homogenerous equation as homogenous

Tags: graph-theory, recurrence-relations, relations

Say I have Fibonacci R.Relation,
$$
r^2=r+1
$$
Can I write it as $r^2-r-1=0$?

From what I know a homogeneous equation is an equation equated to zero.

Comment: Homogeneous can mean other things than a zero RHS.  Homogeneous is also used for polynomial equations where all terms have equal total degree.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of recurrence relations, homogenous relates to linear recurrences. In the Fibonacci example, $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n$ is homogeneous since it is linear in the sequence elements without further constants. Scaling the sequence gives another solution. Homogenous linear recurrences with constant coefficients can be solved with an exponential or geometric ansatz, $F_n=r^n$. From that results the quadratic characteristic equation $r^2=r+1$, which is very much non-homogenous.

Answer (score 0):

That equation could be made to have homogeneous ("the same") degree by introducing a new variable, say $r^2 - rs - s^2 = 0$.

This sort of thing is typical in studying curves in projective geometry.

Comment: so,im doing the right thing?

Comment: What I did was a little different than what you did.  I don't consider moving all the terms to one side as making an equation homogeneous.  Perhaps you should explain the context, so I can better tell what you were asked to do.